# C++ 11 / 14 - Is there a raw pointer wrapper for a resource managed elsewhere?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, c++14

I have a pointer to an instance of a structure which is managed internally by a library.

Therefore I do not need to manage it (memory management, I don't need to delete it) however I need the raw pointer for access.

Is there a C++ 11 / 14 object for wrapping a raw pointer? Basically a unique ptr without a deleter.

Or should I simply use a raw pointer?

Comment: There's is nothing wrong with a non owning raw pointer, as there's nothing wrong with references, as there's nothing wrong with the `this` pointer

Comment: Why do you want to wrap something if the wrapper has **no** functionality ?

Comment: Use a raw pointer for a non-owning pointer.  Unless it cannot be nullptr, in which case prefer a raw reference.  If it can be const, make it a pointer to a const, or a const reference.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr ?

Comment: I suspect `unique_ptr` is quickly going to become tedious, as you can then only have one 'live' instance which must be passed round the code, which generates quite unnatural code.
But if you are ok with that and just want to use the `unique_ptr` as a decoration to say you know who owns the resource, you could define a sensibly named dummy deleter as the second argument. Alternatively, if there is also a library function that deletes the resource, why not introduce that as the second argument of your unique_ptr? Or go the whole hog and use shared_ptr with a custom deleter.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest gsl-like syntactic sugar to mark that it is not the pointer you manage. Something like:

```
template<class T>
using observer = T;

observer<library_managed_object *> foo = nullptr;
```

You can also use, as sugested elsewhere the `observer_ptr`.

And one final word - in world of C++11 and so forth - using raw pointers is perfectly reasonable when you want to pass something like nullable non owning reference. If smart pointers shows ownership then lack of one - shows lack of ownership. All in all - if you do not have legacy code with manually managed memory - don't be afraid to use raw pointers. As says Herb Sutter:

> Pass by * or & to accept a widget independently of how the caller is
>   managing its lifetime. Most of the time, we don’t want to commit to a
>   lifetime policy in the parameter type, such as requiring the object be
>   held by a specific smart pointer, because this is usually needlessly
>   restrictive. As usual, use a * if you need to express null (no
>   widget), otherwise prefer to use a &; and if the object is input-only,
>   write const widget* or const widget&.

https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [gsl::owner](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/pointers) defined in the GSL project.
Its not a type but more of a tag to define ownership.

The [CPP core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-raw) define the use case of `gsl::owner`

> mark owning pointers using owner from the guideline support library:

```
 owner<X*> compute(args)    // It is now clear that ownership is transferred 
 {
     owner<X*> res = new X{};
     // ...
     return res; 
 }
```

> This tells analysis tools that res is an owner. That is, its value
>   must be deleted or transferred to another owner, as is done here by
>   the return.
>
> owner is used similarly in the implementation of resource handles.

Another alternative is [observer_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr)

Comment: Also thought of `observer_ptr`. But he is not owning the pointer. `owner` is unclean.